# Check if it is the last entry in a multivalue map

Tags: java

I am new to Java and trying to learn collections. Please suggest me, if there is an easy way to check if a particular

```
(key,value)
```

pair is the last entry in the [apache.commons.collections4.MultiValueMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html).

Tried using

```
.hasNext()
```

and it is not working.

Tried Code:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> testMap = new MultiValueMap<String, String>();
if (atlastMap.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println("Found a way");                          
}
```

Comment: Well it really depends what the underlying map is. If it's a `HashMap`, there is no 'order' per se, but a `TreeMap` on the other hand does have a defined order. Can you post more context code of what you've tried?

Comment: From what I see in the docs, there is no "last" entry in any meaningful sense.

Comment: @Arkadiy Assuming OP doesn't actually mean a [MultiValuedMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html), then the wrapped map could be a SortedMap

Comment: Response to update - There is no 'last entry' with the default constructor, as the underlying map is a HashMap, which is unordered.

Comment: @lucasvw Ah! and the `collectionFactory` can produce lists. That makes sense.

Comment: @Arkadiy Actually am not understanding the discussion. Sorry could you please explain.

Comment: @lucasvw Actually am not understanding the discussion. Sorry could you please explain.

Comment: @SureshbabuKishore The MultiValueMap, as you have defined it, does not have an order, so it is impossible to check the 'last entry'. Can you clarify why you need to check the 'last entry'?

Comment: @lucasvw There is no use case as such. I am just trying to learn, I thought 'hasNext()' was the one surprised to know it didnt work

Comment: @SureshbabuKishore, well for one, MultiValueMap does not have a 'hasNext()' method, and two, 'hasNext()' is typically associated with an Iterator, where it checks if there is a next value in the iteration. I'm not sure why you thought it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> testMap = new MultiValueMap<String, String>();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = testMap.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry<String, String> pair = iterator.next();
    // do something
}
```